# apt-extracttemplates: What for?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

Can somebody explain to me what the purpose of apt-extracttemplates? I am not even aware of this program until recently, having been using Debian-based systems for more than five years. I could not find anything on the web about this program other than the dry manual pages.

Answer (score 0):

The man page gives information about its purpose.

In any case it was written to have an extractor that could be quickly run over all the to be unpacked .debs before apt called dpkg itself (and to pre-feed those to debconf), as at the time there was no option in dpkg-deb to easily extract the control tar member from the .deb. Right now we've got dpkg-deb --ctrl-tarfile which could probably replace it, but I've not benchmarked that to know if running it for each .deb would incur a significant performance difference.